# Is there any way to add ng-model-options dynamically using directives?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, compilation

I want to add this option when my directive it's compiled.

I've been trying with this:

HTML

```
<input ng-model="myValue" my-directive>
```

JS

```
angular
  .module('myApp')
  .directive('myDirective', directive);

directive.$inject = ['$compile'];
function directive($compile){
  var ddo = {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: {pre: prelinkFn} 
  };
 return ddo;

 function prelinkFn(scope, element, attrs){

  attr['ngModelOptions'] = { updateOn: 'blur' };

  //I think that in this function, when i compile the element, the attributes 
  //are compiled too, but this is not working
  $compile(element)(scope);
 }  
}
```

**My questions:**

1. What have I been doing wrong?
2. There are other way to bind the "blur" option for the ng-model assignment?

Comment: you can bind the options object to scope and provide a reference to the object in `ng-model-options`

Comment: My idea it's adding dinamically `ng-model-options` directive, not adding dinamically the object option.

Comment: why? does it make any difference ? you will get default behavior for an empty object

Comment: the diference it's that if you try to adding dinamically option, the developer it's obligated to define the `ng-model-options` directive. My goal it's add this directive through my directive (and also other functionality).

Comment: `and also other functionality`, these words are usually a clue to write an adapter. what you could do is instead of using an `<input>` with a directive, write a directive with a template that already has an `<input>` and the `ng-model-options`, and provide anything else you need via scope

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `ngModelCtrl.$options`:

```
app.directive("myDirective", function($compile){
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, iElem, iAttrs, ngModelCtrl) {
            ngModelCtrl.$options = {
                updateOn: 'blur',
                updateOnDefault: true,
                debounce: {
                    'blur': 1000,
                    'default': 1000
                }
            }
            // Then do what you want... :)
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Not sure your version of angular, but this isn't the case for >1.6  
ngModelCtrl.$overrideModelOptions({updateOn:'blur'})